# C++: undefined reference to const pointer when declaring as extern

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I get a compiler error when programming the following:

- file1.cpp: declaring/defining of several variables
- file1.cpp: defining a pointer array that is pointing to each of these variables **-> this array shall be const (=always point to these variables)**
- file2.cpp: here I want to use the pointer array and use the variables it points to.

```
    //file1.cpp
    int a,b,c,d;
    int *const pa[4] = {&a, &b, &c, &d};

    //file2.cpp
    extern int *const pa[4];
```

when compiling it drops the error in file2.cpp:

```
undefined reference to `pa'
```

How to define that pointer array with constant pointers and use it in different source files?

Best regards :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `const` variable has internal linkage by default. To get external linkage, add `extern` to the definition:

```
extern int *const pa[4] = {&a, &b, &c, &d};
```

Comment: Or probably cleaner: Put the `extern int *const pa[4];` declaration in a header and include it in both `file1.cpp` and `file2.cpp`. This avoids type mismatch.

Comment: Thank you. It's working now.
Knowing this, after another 5min research I found, that what I did above is working with variables. Using a const always requires an `extern` even at the definition. 
Or as walnut mentioned to put it in a header.